# Solve for $m=0,1,2,...$ and $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ the integral $\int_{\Gamma_1} z^n(1-z)^mdz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I need to solve the integral for $m=0,1,2, ...$, and $n\in\Bbb{Z}$

$$\int_{\Gamma_1} z^n(1-z)^m\,dz$$

where $\Gamma_1$ is the circle centered in $0$ with radius $1$.

I'm struggling trying to see this integral in a way I can use Cauchy's Integral Formula or Cauchy's Integral Formula for derivatives, but so far I'm stuck trying to rewrite it. So could anyone give me any hint to point me in the right direction to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that $\int_\Gamma f(z) dz =0$ if $f$ has no pole inside $\Gamma$?

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, but if I take $m=0$ and $n=-1$ then $\int_{\Gamma_1} z^{-1}dz$ is $2i\pi$ which is not zero, that's where I'm confused.

Comment: Oh I missed that I thought $n.m$ are always in $\mathbb N$. So can you use the residue?

Comment: @JohnMa I believe I can't, since in class we've not seen it yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Cauchy's Integral formula: When $n\geq 0$, $z^n (1-z)^m$ is analytic and so the integral is zero. When $n<0$, set $a=0$ and $f(z) = (1-z)^m$, the Cauchy integral formula is

$$f^{(k-1)}(0) = \frac{k!}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^k} dz.$$
and so putting $k = -n$ gives

$$\int_\Gamma z^n(1-z)^m dz = \frac{2\pi i}{|n|!}\frac{d^{|n|-1}}{dz^{|n|-1}} (1-z)^m\bigg|_{z=0}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see it that way. But just one more thing, shouldn't it be $f^{(n-1)}(a)$ on the first equation?